# How do I attach an inline image to a rails 4.2 mailer using paperclip?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, actionmailer

I'm using rails 4.2 and use paperclip to handle my image uploads. I am trying to attach the image from my model to an email. Per the Rails guides I have my mailer like so

```
def sub_conversion_email(user, blend)
    @user = user
    @blend = blend
    attachments.inline[@blend.image.original_filename] = File.read(@blend.image.url(:medium))
    mail(to: @user.email, subject: "A subject...")
  end
```

Then in my mailer view I have

```
<%= image_tag attachments[@blend.image.original_filename].url %>
```

For some reason I'm getting the error
`No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /system/blends/images/000/000/015/medium/filename.jpg`

What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: what directory are they actually in?

Comment: in this particular example, `public/system/blends/images/000/000/015/medium/`. paperclip puts the files in `/public/system/:model_name/`

Comment: right, so it's treating the path as an absolute path rather than a relative one? That ay be due to you using the word `url` instead of `path` ???? (note: guessing.. but something to google?)

Answer (score 1):

So thanks to Taryn East pointing out that I needed to use `path` instead of `url` in the `File.read()`, it is working. The only thing is that in the mailer preview, it won't show the image. When I inspect the image, its src is `cid:........................mycomputer.mail`. When I actually send the email, it works just fine. Anyone know how to get it to show in the mailer preview?